Could rocket exhaust eventually lead to detrimental effects from interplanetary space pollution?
I am interested in if the exhaust from a rocket would lead to space pollution like space junk does. Particularly, I am talking about the exhaust that stays in interplanetary orbit and does not return to our atmosphere. When a rocket ejects its propellent, wouldn't some of it stay in interplanetary space? And, if so, why would or wouldn't this exhaust be harmful over time, especially with the increase in spacecraft launches every year. This gas would be traveling at high speeds, and I would think that gravity would clump some types of exhaust together to form pellets that could damage satellites and rockets. If this truly is an issue, is there anything we can do about it?

Presumably most of the fuel combustion products exhaust in the atmosphere which is more problematic to living systems and atmospheric chemistry, the orbital exhausts must be a tiny fraction of the fuels that put the vehicle as it were up there. And as stated solar wind fluxes must also dwarf attitude and positional adjustment thrusting.

The sun emits ~1.5 million tons per second of solar wind. Rocket exhaust is a drop in the bucket - we've launched ~20 thousand tons into space total.

The answers that say that space is big and rocket fuel is tiny are right, but it should be noted that the fuel mass of the Apollo lunar landers is on the same order of magnitude of the whole mass of the lunar atmosphere. Therefore, there was a time half a century ago when a sizeable part of the lunar atmosphere was made of rocket exhaust. However, it's unlikely that it had any detrimental effect.

different but related: Does "What happens beyond Kármán, stay beyond Kármán"?

@Pere A large percent increase in a small number is still a small number; obligatory xkcd. Even after all current landings the atmosphere is still considered vacuum for all intents and purposes (only around a thousand times the pressure of vacuums we can artifice for scientific purposes).

If you mean a rocket in broadly the same near-Earth orbit as that space junk, how could its exhaust not add to planetary pollution?
Whether your rocket exhaust could lead to interplanetary space pollution is a very different Question.
Whether interplanetary space pollution could lead to detrimental effects is another different Question.
Through all those scenarios, roughly what proportion of the spatial volume could be polluted by your rocket and what effect could there be on empty space?

@TLW and that solar wind is radiating out in all directions, diminishing with the inverse square law.

@RonJohn - and carrying your rocket exhaust along with it out, dissipating said exhaust through inverse-square in the process.

Individual particles of rocket exhaust (often, but not always, individual molecules) are far far too small to avoid being affected by the solar wind.

@TLW you'd think that tiny, highly dispersed molecules would rarely be hit by protons and electrons already dispersed by the solar wind.

Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39651/would-rocket-engine-exhaust-create-pockets-of-gas-in-space-which-could-hinder-fu

@RonJohn - effective ionization cross section of proton-water collisions at 10kev is ~10^-19m^2. Solar wind at 1au is ~5×10^12 particles/m^2/s. This is ~1 ionizing collision per 25 days on average - and the moment you're ionized you interact far more with the solar wind.

No, this isn't an issue. Space is big, and the exhaust gases rapidly disperse, eventually merging with the solar wind. Exhaust can produce some solids, eg carbon, but these particles are microscopic and unlikely to condense. Some exhaust gas and dust can orbit the Sun, but most of it will dissipate.
From my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/551141/123208

the solar wind [is] a stream of charged particles released from the upper atmosphere of the Sun which blows through the solar system. This wind is very thin - in Earth terms it's a hard vacuum, but it is moving quickly.
The solar wind is observed to exist in two fundamental states, termed the slow solar wind and the fast solar wind. Near Earth, the slow solar wind has a speed of 300 - 500 km/s, and a temperature around 100,000 K, the fast solar wind has a typical speed of 750 km/s and a temperature around 800,000 K.

So the solar wind and solar radiation pressure tends to push exhaust gases to the far reaches of the solar system, and into the interstellar medium.

I'm not 100% on board with how absolutely you phrased this answer. What's true is that the combustion in liquid-fueled rockets produces exhaust that consists almost exclusively of gases that then disperse, but there are some details where it's less clear-cut: ablatively cooled nozzles, solid-fueled stages, ignition mechanisms...

@leftaroundabout I tried to not make an absolute statement. Sure, there are other solids possible, apart from carbon, especially with solid fuels, eg metals and metallic oxides, nitrides, chlorides, etc. But those solid particles are tiny, and don't tend to form clumps when ejected at high speed and temperature. I think "these particles are microscopic and unlikely to condense" covers that adequately.

OTOH, yes, some solids can condense on nozzle surfaces, and then clumps of that "soot" can be dislodged...

Plus, I don't know of any solid rocket motors that are used in interplanetary space. The only ones I know of are ullage motors (very small) and SRBs (used in the first stage and usually fall back down to Earth).

ObHHGTtG: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Chapter_8

@controlgroup apogee kick motors are often solids for reliability reasons and quick burn times. This apparently includes geostationary satellites, despite the potential weight savings with better Isp. The new horizons probe that went to pluto even used a solid kick motor as its final stage.

Well, today I learned. (Those are still tiny motors - compared to SRBs that do produce a ton of waste gas.)

The total mass of the (natural) interplanetary dust cloud is approximately $3.5×10^{16}$ kg. That's 7 billion Starship launchers. There is no conceivable way for humans to add significantly to interplanetary dust with present technology.

In most space flight configurations, most if not all propellants "outside" of the Earth's atmosphere use either liquid hydrogen as fuel and LOX (liquid oxygen) as the oxidizer, or hypergolic propellants which consist of hydrazine variants as the fuel along with an oxidizer such as nitrogen tetroxide. Both of these fuel/oxidizer combos produce water vapor as a byproduct of combustion. As such, water vapor poses no threat to space.
The emissions of solid rocket fuels and other liquid fuel types used in most rocket booster stages will be confined to the Earth's atmosphere.

Are you building engines that move planets?  Like, did you lower a moon-scale thrusters into Jupiter and are burning its Hydrogen in a fusion candle to turn Jupiter into an interstellar space craft?
(You build a large hydrogen collector and two fusion engines on a planetoid (or structure on that size).  You lower this into Jupiter, and fire both in balance.  The inward one pushes on Jupiter itself, and the outer one provides thrust; the net effect is you have a rocket engine pushing Jupiter.  You fuel it by gathering hydrogen from Jupiter atmosphere.  Note that this will get insanely hot and insanely turbulent, as the rocket plume will warm up the atmosphere near you; this is K1 or K2-scale planetary engineering.)
If you are doing planetary engineering on this kind of scale, you start having to worry about your rocket exhaust messing with the solar system.
If you are merely launching rockets from a planet to do light exploration, space is insanely big, and the sun pushes a large amount of gas out of the solar system already.  The existing solar wind is on the order of millions of tonnes of gas per second - spread over the entire sphere of the solar system, but still, it is a lot.
Local emissions could mess with that, but you'd have to be somewhere in that neighborhood, which is far beyond our current level of space faring capability.

@TheRocketfan if you read this well-reasoned and well-received answer in its entirety, the concept of fusion candles is offered as an illustration of just how far one would have to go before one could achieve "interplanetary space pollution". I don't think your comment is helpful or warranted. Keep reading all the way through to the end of the answer post and you'll see why.

Small amounts of gasses and solids or not we are still governed by Sir Newton. After hundreds of years of heavily polluting Earth's atmosphere such that we can hardly breathe it, the comments here still nay say as if what happens here will not happen in space.
Small changes can create large problems.
